# progress bar percentage moving along with the bar dynamically?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I'm looking for an effect that could be used in a progress bar animation and i have no idea where to search for it - the basic idea is that you have a progress bar and what i would like to do is show the percentage that is loaded just above the loading "core" of the bar. So not on the left, not on the right, but above and dynamic, following and moving along with the loading colored core of the bar. Detailed effect: numbers are counting up as well as they are moving along the line ( like with the countUp.js effect), and loading core + numbers speed are slowing down as they reach the specified percentage limit.

Not sure if i made myself clear, and i am pretty sure i must have seen this somewhere. Any ideas perhaps?

Comment: Learn how to ask question http://stackoverflow.com//help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how much more concise to be, i am not a programmer at all and i have no idea what technologies i am looking for, so i just want to know if someone can direct me to where i could find the above said effect. Sorry if my non-programmer language is not accurate:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question could definitely use some tidying up. Here's something that might might help answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/grhgnz61/2/

Important to note is that the number container is placed inside the bar and made position absolute so that it is always positioned to the far right of the progress bar.

```
.progressBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: steelblue;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.progressNumber {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -1em;
    color: #eee;
}
```

There could be better ways to do this. But until you fix your question, there's not much better help that can be given.

Comment: Thank you so so much, that's just what i needed for a start!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct.

Comment: I would upvote but i need 15 reputation apparently, and i only got 1, i will just mark the answer as correct if that is all i can do:)